# Array of pointers and file I/O in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *strs[6], array[100];
    int i;
    FILE *file  = fopen("random.txt", "r");

    for (i=0 ; i<6; i++)
    {
        fscanf(file ,"%s", array);
        strs[i]= array;

        printf("%s ", strs[i]);
    }

    printf("%s", strs[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

Inside the random.txt:

one two three four five six

Output is:
one two three four five six **six**

My question is why the last one 'six', I cannot access third element that is 'four'. Why doesn not record them in char array of pointers?

Comment: `strs[i]= array;` -> `strs[i]= strdup(array);` If there is no `strdup` use `malloc/memcpy` to get the same. Here all the pointers point to array and that array contains `six` at last.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that all element in your array of pointers, i.e. `strs`, points to `array`. In other words - `strs[0]` points to `array`, `strs[1]` points to `array`, `strs[2]` points to `array` and so on.

So when you change `array` all elements in `strs` points to the new value.

It can be fixed in several ways but the easiest way is:

```
//char *strs[6], array[100];
char strs[6][100];
```

and

```
// fscanf(file ,"%s", array);
// strs[i]= array;
fscanf(file ,"%s", strs[i]);
```

However, notice that your code has no check for buffer overflow (which is bad). I'll recommend that you read about `fgets`

Answer (score 0):

You shall use strcpy from string.h library

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char strs[6][100] , array[100];
    int i;
    FILE *file  = fopen("random.txt", "r");

    for (i=0 ; i<6; i++)
    {
        fscanf(file ,"%s", array);
        strcpy(strs[i], array) ;

        printf("%s ", strs[i]);
    }

    printf("%s", strs[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This invokes *undefined behavior*. You're using an indeterminate pointer for the target of a `strcpy()`. `char strs[6][100]`, or use dynamic allocation to address this. It's still begging for a buffer overflow, but at least it won't be UB from inception.